# Google Composer / Airflow - connection to MongoDB Atlas

Tags: mongodb, airflow, mongodb-atlas

We have an airflow task that adds data to the mongodb server.
We can connect to the mongodb server only behind IP Access or VPC Peering.
We are having issues with VPC Peering, so we thought we can just enable direct IP access between the airflow workers and the mongodb server

Has anyone done that?
If not, do you have another suggestion?

Comment: Have you found a solution to this?